# Java Persistance: Objects arent initialized anymore after changing annotations

Tags: java, jpa, h2

I experienced some problems with deleting objects from the database (h2) and found out that there was a problem with my relations:

```
@Entity
public class PizzaOrder {

//...
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Pizza> orderList = new ArrayList<>();
//...
```

My class PizzaOrder stores multiple Pizzas. The "mappedBy=" was missing here. The Pizza class itself had no field for the corresponding pizzaOrder.

I changed the code to the following:

```
@Entity
public class PizzaOrder {

//...
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pizzaOrder")
private List<Pizza> orderList = new ArrayList<>();
//...
```

And:

```
@Entity
public class Pizza {

//...
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="pizzaOrder_ID")
private PizzaOrder pizzaOrder;
//...
```

After this change, I launched the application and realized that my test orders I create arent there anymore, the list is empty. While with the previous implementation it at least worked for this part.

The test data is created like this:

```
        Pizza pizza1 = new Pizza(salamiPizza, PizzaSize.MEDIUM);
        Pizza pizza2 = new Pizza(schinkenPizza, PizzaSize.LARGE);
        Pizza pizza3 = new Pizza(pilzPizza, PizzaSize.MEDIUM);
        pizzaRespository.save(pizza1);
        pizzaRespository.save(pizza2);
        pizzaRespository.save(pizza3);

        PizzaOrder pizzaorder1 = new PizzaOrder(2000);
        pizzaorder1.addToOrderList(pizza1);
        pizzaorder1.addToOrderList(pizza2);
        pizzaOrderRespository.save(pizzaorder1);

        PizzaOrder pizzaorder2 = new PizzaOrder(2001);
        pizzaorder2.addToOrderList(pizza3);
        pizzaOrderRespository.save(pizzaorder2);
```

Is there something crucial I am missing?

PS: **I just tested another part of the application where a pizza gets created and stored in a newly created order object. When I check this order, I can see my pizza object.**

Comment: Where do you initialize Pizza.pizzaOrder? That's the crucial part.

Comment: So I do have to set this value by myself?

Comment: Yes. That's the owning side of the association. If you don't set it, the association doesn't exist for JPA.

Comment: Okay that totally makes sense.  But where is the best point to do that? I kind of difficult scince I cant save the pizzas before i set that, but i cant save the orders before i save the pizzas.

Comment: You usuelly set that inside the `addToOrderList()` method. Create and persist the pizzaq, then add them to the order and save the order. Or add a PERSIST cascade on orderList association so that the pizza are are also persisted when you persist the order.

Comment: So inside my `addToOrderList()` it would be something like `pizza.setPizzaOrder(this).` But that doesnt seem to work, when I look at the value later its not set.

Comment: Is all this code running inside a transaction? It should.

Comment: My example data (pizza1, pizza2) is initialized when the application starts (CommandLineRunner). I am using Spring MVC to create a web app. I just checked what happens when i create a pizza/order in my controller, this appears to work - i can open the order and see the containments there.